# ajax.Actionlink OnComplete never being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-javascript, actionlink

I am using @Ajax.ActionLink to delete a record:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete","DeleteRun",new {RunId = run.RunId},
                     new AjaxOptions() { Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this entry?",
                                        HttpMethod = "DELETE",
                                        OnComplete = string.Format("DeleteRunInTable({0});",run.RunId)

                     })
```

Which produces the following link:

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-complete="DeleteRunInTable(11);" data-ajax-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this entry?" data-ajax-method="DELETE" href="/Runs/Delete/11">Delete</a>
```

The delete is working perfectly but the OnComplete javascript function "DeleteRunInTable" is never called (i put a breakpoint in the javascript). Anyone know why?

Here is the javascript function (included as an external file):

```
    function DeleteRunInTable(RunId) {
       $("tr[data-runid=" + RunId).remove();
}
```

I've checked in chrome developer tools to make sure the script is loading ok and it is. I also made sure jquery and jquery unobtrusive were being included.

Comment: Can you call DeleteRunInTable from the Javascript console?

Comment: Not sure yet. I'll try when i get home tonight (where the code is). I'm relatively new to web development in general especially javascript & Jquery so i never even used the javascript console but i'll try when i get home and let you know the results.

Comment: Javascript has some quirky scoping rules. If your function is somehow not defined in a global scope, then it probably won't exist when the OnComplete method is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks i got it working. I changed the function a little:

```
function DeleteRunInTable(RunId) {
    //$("tr[data-runid=" + RunId).remove();
    $("tr[data-runid='" + String(RunId) + "']").remove();
    return false;
}
```

Don't know why it wasn't stopping at the break point before but now its working fine.